# UnitTest for a module using Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

I would like to test the behaviour of a module (using [Marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette)) which works (1).

Oddly, the js-module (1) works but the unit test (2)  using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) fails.

Any ideas?

---

(1)

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'marionette',
    'tasks/views/item',
    'text!tasks/templates/list.html',
    'collections/tasks'
], function (Marionette, itemView, listTemplate, TaskCollection) {
    "use strict";

    var ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new TaskCollection();
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        template: listTemplate,

        itemView: itemView,

        appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
            collectionView.$el.find('ul.tasks').append(itemView.el);
        }

    });

    return ListView;
});
```

---

(2)

```
        // spec file
        it("should add a new element", function () {
            // TODO
            var itemView = new Backbone.View(),
                collectionView = new Backbone.View();
            this.view.appendHtml(collectionView, itemView);
            expect(this.view.$el.find('ul.tasks').length).toEqual(1); 
            // Expected 0 to equal 1.
        });
```

Comment: have you set up the tests to work with RequireJS? if not, there are tutorials around the web for doing that. what errors are you getting from the tests?

Comment: @DerickBailey the error which I get is `Expected 0 to equal 1.`. I suppose that running `this.view.appendHtml(collectionView, itemView);`should add a new element such as in (1).

Comment: Could you please set up a jsFiddle that shows this in action? I'm not familiar enough with Marionette, Backbone, and Jasmine to set it up myself, but I think I could get it working if I had something to start with.

Answer (score 3):

```
var itemView = new Backbone.View(),
    collectionView = new Backbone.View();
    this.view.appendHtml(collectionView, itemView);
```

Sorry, but what do you want to accomplish here? It seems to me you append something to `collectionView.$el.find('ul.tasks')` at the moment, when `collectionView.$el` is just empty. So `collectionView.$el.find('ul.tasks')` returns nothing and so on.

Add `console.log()` to check this:

```
appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
     console.log(collectionView.$el.html());
     collectionView.$el.find('ul.tasks').append(itemView.el);
}
```

Comment: +1 yes you are right. but how should I test this piece of code?

Comment: thanks for your time. Post me a comment when the example will be posted.